# how to remove error "Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I make a demo of `react-router` .but I am getting this error
**Cannot read property 'location' of undefined** 
here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Router,Route,Link,hashHistory} from 'react-router'
import Hello from './Hello';

const Home =()=> <div><h1>home</h1><Links/></div>;
const About =()=> <div><h1>About</h1><Links/></div>;
const Contact =()=> <div><h1>Contact</h1><Links/></div>

const Links =()=> 
  <nav>
  <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
    <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
    <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
</nav>

const App = () => (
  <Router history ={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component ={Home}></Route>
    <Route path="/about" component ={About}></Route>
     <Route path="/contact" component ={Contact}></Route>

  </Router>
);

render(



  <App />

  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/qYvvYWyAG

Comment: I created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yP9gVExDn
It seems that you have to use `react-router-dom` and not `react-router` PLUS change the `hashHistory` to an instance of `history/createBrowserHistory`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/82QO88mLl:

```
 import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
 import {Router,Route,Link,Switch} from 'react-router'
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
 import Hello from './Hello';

const Home =()=> <div><h1>home</h1></div>;
const About =()=> <div><h1>About</h1></div>;
const Contact =()=> <div><h1>Contact</h1></div>;


const App = () => (
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
   <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
   <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
   </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
  );

   render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You are using version 4 which has different sintax